# How to remove the single quotes around a String in Bash script?

Tags: sql, bash, shell, file, scripting

I have a shell script (.sh) file written and It stores the result of an SQL query into a file.

The results of SQL file needs to be converted into INSERT queries in bulk.

There are three columns in the SQL query and they are written into a file using the following command

```
mysql -u$db_user -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3308 < my_query.sql > my_results_into_file
```

Now I do some manipulations on the file `my_results_into_file`

```
sed -i.bak -e $'s/\t/\x27,\x27/g' my_results_into_file # replace tabs in output with commas, add single quotes around values
sed -i.bak -e '1d' my_results_into_file # remove first line from the file (column names)
sed -i.bak -e $'s/^/INSERT INTO mytable(column1, column2, column3) VALUES(\x27/' my_results_into_file # build inserts
sed -i.bak -e $'s/$/\x27);/' my_results_into_file # build inserts
```

The above script leads a problem because there is a NULLABLE column in the Query and It can contain NULL and that will make NULL value to be enclosed by single quote and is treated as 'NULL' and is a string.

Is there a way that in one of the scripts I can escape putting single quotes around NULL ???

Answer (score 1):

Since you're running the data through a series of `sed` commands I'm thinking the easiest solution will be one more `sed`, eg:

```
$ echo "insert into mytable values ('a',123,'NULL');" | sed "s/'NULL'/NULL/g"
insert into mytable values ('a',123,NULL);
```

Now, whether you do that as another standalone `sed` call, eg:

```
$ sed -i.bak -e $"s/'NULL'/NULL/g" my_reulsts_into_file
```

Or convert, say, your first `sed` call into a multi-pattern `sed` call, eg:

```
$ sed -i.bak -e $"s/\t/\x27,\x27/g; s/'NULL'/NULL/g" my_results_into_file
```

... that's up to you to decide.

Comment: Good stuff. Also note that each iteration of current code wipes out the "original" file, saved with `-i.bak` once the 2nd `sed` is called. Bye-bye, original file ;-) You can also put all cmds in one file and call it like `sed -i.bak -f mySedScript DataFile`. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter - agreed; unfortunately the OP appears to have a history of providing no feedback so not sure how much of these responses (answers/comments) are getting through ...

Comment: I would want to avoid adding Single quotes around NULL value of a column. The above solution says to get Rid of Single quotes around NULL. Is there a way to avoid adding Single Quotes around NULL ? The reason behind that is, If there is a String with value 'NULL' in the output of SQL query, this solution will strip off `''` and consider it as NULL which I dont want to do.

Comment: It's not clear from what's been posted (so far) as to how you would know which `NULL` values should be quoted or not; this is going to come down to how your SQL generates/displays `'NULL'` vs `NULL`; in other words, we don't know what the raw data from the SQL query(s) look like re: `'NULL'` and `NULL`